Show $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{f\left(nx\right)}{n^2}=0$ a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$ if $f \in L^1\left([0,T]\right)$ and periodic.
Show $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{f\left(nx\right)}{n^2}=0$ a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$ if $f \in L^1\left([0,T]\right)$ and periodic in $\mathbb{R}$, where $T>0$ is the period.
My idea is as follows: it is easy to demonstrate $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}$ and then we have
$$
\int_{[0,T]}\frac{\left|f(nx)\right|}{n^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{n^3}\int_{[0,nT]}\left|f(x)\right|\mathrm{d}x=\frac{c}{n^2}
$$
where $c=\int_{[0,T]}\left|f(x)\right|\mathrm{d}x<\infty$. Therefore we have
$$
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{[0,T]}\frac{\left|f(nx)\right|}{n^2}\mathrm{d}x=0
$$
and so $\frac{\left|f(nx)\right|}{n^2}$ is $L^1$ convergent to 0. Therefore we can show it converges to 0 in measure and then there is a subsequence which converges to 0 a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
However, I encounter problems when showing the whole sequence converges to 0 a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$, can anyone give me some hints?

In general, you can show that if $(X, \mu)$ is a measure space such that $f, f_1 , f_2, \ldots$ belong to $L^1 (X)$ and $\sum_n \left( \int_{X} \left| f_n -f \right| \right) < +\infty$ then $f_n$ converges to $f$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.  (Hint: Use Markov's inequality.)

We can use a Borel-Cantelli argument. Let $f_n(x) = n^{-2}f(nx)$. First, we observe that for each $\epsilon > 0$,
$$m(\{x \in [0,T] : |f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon\}) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^T |f_n(x)|\,dx = \frac{c}{n^2\epsilon}.$$
Summing,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(\{x \in [0,T] : |f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon\}) \leq \frac{c}{\epsilon}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty.$$
So, by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, the set of $x \in [0,T]$ such that $|f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$ has measure $0$. In particular, for almost every $x \in [0,T]$, there exists an $N$ sufficiently large that $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. This proves that $f_n \to 0$ for almost every $x\in [0,T]$, so by periodicity for almost every $x \in \mathbb R$.

I think in your first equation it should be $\frac1\epsilon$ instead of $\frac1{\epsilon^2}$ (it does not change a lot if $\epsilon$ is small enough)

Yes, thanks for pointing that out.
